# parsing curl response into readable table

Tags: php, curl

I sent a curl request to a server and get the following results:

```
{ "data": [
    { "state_msg": "Canceled", 
      "dpc": null, 
      "mgcp_call_ids": null, 
      "code": 487,"mgcp_mgc_ip": null, 
      "dst_codecs": "G729,telephone-event,H264,H263", 
      "megaco_mg_ip": null,"src_codecs": 
      "G729,PCMU,telephone-event,H264,H263", 
      "q850_state_details": null, 
      "pid":1383031680, 
      "call_time": null
.......
```

How can i parse this into readable fields?  I am looking for something like foreach loop, or something similar.

if this were xml i could do

```
 $response->data->state_msg.
```

Clearly that wont work here.  what can i do?

Comment: That looks an awful lot like JSON to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a JSON response. Pass the string through `json_decode` to receive the object and iterate over it as you would any other object.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
$json_string = '{"data": {"state_msg": "Canceled", "dpc": null, "mgcp_call_ids": null, "code": 487,"mgcp_mgc_ip": null, "dst_codecs": "G729,telephone-event,H264,H263", "megaco_mg_ip": null,"src_codecs": "G729,PCMU,telephone-event,H264,H263", "q850_state_details": null, "pid":1383031680, "call_time": null}');
$obj = json_decode($json_string);
```

It will turn your JSON into an array and you can read it like this

```
echo $obj->data->state_msg;
```